# How can I disable double quotes auto-escaping in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, escaping, phpstorm

PhpStorm auto-escapes double quotes when storing data to the database.

I have a JSON string that I want to store to the database but PhpStorm automatically escapes double quotes.

How can I disable this?

Comment: How do you store that string into database? What kind of database are you using? Are you using copy and past?
Please, describe the workflow and show me some code.

Comment: Are you talking about copy-paste? As that is the only "auto escape" that I can think of. If so -- just use `Edit | Paste Simple` instead of just `Paste` to prevent any escaping on paste. if it's something different, provide details/screenshots/etc